# How to convert JSON post request to a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, json, dataframe

im new to python and pandas but would like to do some real statistics on population in Sweden as a fun project. To retrieve this SCB (statistics database of Sweden) has an API. I have come pretty far with this code below to access some data, but I still don't know how to convert the response to a pandas DataFrame.

Below is my code:

```
import json
import requests
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd

#API Settings
url="http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/sv/ssd/"
amnesid="BE/"
level1="BE0101/"
level2="BE0101A/"
level3="BefolkningNy/"
urlPost= url + amnesid + level1 +level2 +level3

#Post Request
url = urlPost
payload = {
"query": [{"code":"Region", "selection":{"filter":"item",
"values":["00"]}}],
"response": {"format":"json"}
}


r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
print(r.text)
```

Here is the console output:

```
{"columns":[{"code":"Region","text":"region","type":"d"}, 
{"code":"Tid","text":"år","type":"t"}, 
{"code":"BE0101N1","text":"Folkmängd","comment":"Uppgifterna avser 
förhållandena den 31 december för valt/valda år enligt den regionala 
indelning som gäller den 1 januari året efter.\r\n","type":"c"}, 
{"code":"BE0101N2","text":"Folkökning","comment":"Folkökningen definieras 
som 
skillnaden mellan folkmängden vid årets början och årets 
slut.\r\n","type":"c"}],"comments":[],"data":[{"key":["00","1968"],"values": 
["7931193",".."]},{"key":["00","1969"],"values":["8004270","73077"]},{"key": 
["00","1970"],"values":["8081142","76872"]},{"key":["00","1971"],"values": 
["8115165","34023"]},{"key":["00","1972"],"values":["8129129","13964"]}, 
{"key":["00","1973"],"values":["8144428","15299"]},{"key": 
["00","1974"],"values":["8176691","32263"]},{"key":["00","1975"],"values": 
["8208442","31751"]},{"key":["00","1976"],"values":["8236179","27737"]}, 
{"key":["00","1977"],"values":["8267116","30937"]},{"key": 
["00","1978"],"values":["8284437","17321"]},{"key":["00","1979"],"values": 
["8303010","18573"]},{"key":["00","1980"],"values":["8317937","14927"]}, 
{"key":["00","1981"],"values":["8323033","5096"]},{"key": 
["00","1982"],"values":["8327484","4451"]},{"key":["00","1983"],"values": 
["8330573","3089"]},{"key":["00","1984"],"values":["8342621","12048"]}, 
{"key":["00","1985"],"values":["8358139","15518"]},{"key": 
["00","1986"],"values":["8381515","23376"]},{"key":["00","1987"],"values": 
["8414083","32568"]},{"key":["00","1988"],"values":["8458888","44805"]}, 
{"key":["00","1989"],"values":["8527036","68148"]},{"key": 
["00","1990"],"values":["8590630","63594"]},{"key":["00","1991"],"values": 
["8644119","53489"]},{"key":["00","1992"],"values":["8692013","47894"]}, 
{"key":["00","1993"],"values":["8745109","53096"]},{"key": 
["00","1994"],"values":["8816381","71272"]},{"key":["00","1995"],"values": 
["8837496","21115"]},{"key":["00","1996"],"values":["8844499","7003"]}, 
{"key":["00","1997"],"values":["8847625","3126"]},{"key": 
["00","1998"],"values":["8854322","6697"]},{"key":["00","1999"],"values": 
["8861426","7104"]},{"key":["00","2000"],"values":["8882792","21366"]}, 
{"key":["00","2001"],"values":["8909128","26336"]},{"key": 
["00","2002"],"values":["8940788","31660"]},{"key":["00","2003"],"values": 
["8975670","34882"]},{"key":["00","2004"],"values":["9011392","35722"]}, 
{"key":["00","2005"],"values":["9047752","36360"]},{"key": 
["00","2006"],"values":["9113257","65505"]},{"key":["00","2007"],"values": 
["9182927","69670"]},{"key":["00","2008"],"values":["9256347","73420"]}, 
{"key":["00","2009"],"values":["9340682","84335"]},{"key": 
["00","2010"],"values":["9415570","74888"]},{"key":["00","2011"],"values": 
["9482855","67285"]},{"key":["00","2012"],"values":["9555893","73038"]}, 
{"key":["00","2013"],"values":["9644864","88971"]},{"key": 
["00","2014"],"values":["9747355","102491"]},{"key":["00","2015"],"values": 
["9851017","103662"]},{"key":["00","2016"],"values":["9995153","144136"]}, 
{"key":["00","2017"],"values":["10120242","125089"]}]}
```

Thankful if someone can help me out.

Comment: Is this what you want? `df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['data'])`

Comment: Yes correct, I want the data which contains the year and the population amount. I tried using your code and print but got this error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Try this: `df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(codecs.decode(bytes(r.text, 'utf-8'), 'utf-8-sig'))['data'])`

Comment: Got KeyError: 'data'. 

So tried removing ['data'] and got this result:
dataset
dimension  {'Region': {'label': 'region', 'category': {'i...
label        Folkmängden efter region, tabellinnehåll och år
source                        Statistiska centralbyrån (SCB)
status                                          {'50': '..'}
updated                                 2018-09-05T11:52:00Z
value      [7931193, 8004270, 8081142, 8115165, 8129129, ...

Which has the values I want but not the years.

Comment: Strange... If I copy/paste you code from the question and add only this line `df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(codecs.decode(bytes(r.text, 'utf-8'), 'utf-8-sig'))['data'])`, everything works

Comment: Sorry for the last post. I had experimented with the format and had it set to JSON-STAT. 

It now works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! Added line of code that helped you as an answer. Will be very grateful if you'll accept it as a correct answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussion in the comments, the answer is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(codecs.decode(bytes(r.text, 'utf-8'), 'utf-8-sig'))['data'])
```